Total Work Done and Energy calculation "error"? - Bike cycling up bridge
I have this question that i have calculated to be 3620.4 J (which is the W_total). The question defines the variables as such:
$$ m = 80 kg $$
$$ V_0 = 4.5 m/s $$
$$ h_bridge = 5.2 m $$
$$ V_f = 3 m/s $$
And is asking for the total work done when you go from the base to the top of the bridge.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
$$ \text{KE} = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 $$
$$ \text{KE}_i = \frac{1}{2} \times 80 \, \text{kg} \times (4.5 \, \text{m/s})^2 = 810 \, \text{J} $$
$$ \text{KE}_f = \frac{1}{2} \times 80 \, \text{kg} \times (3 \, \text{m/s})^2 = 360 \, \text{J}
$$
I then calculated the Potential Energy:
$$ \text{PE} = mgh $$
$$ \text{PE}_i = 0 \, \text{J} $$
$$ \text{PE}_f = 80 \, \text{kg} \times 9.81 \, \text{m/s}^2 \times 5.2 \, \text{m} = 4070.4 \, \text{J} $$
Finally I calculated the total mechanical energy:
$$ W_{\text{total}} = (\text{KE}_f + \text{PE}_f) - (\text{KE}_i + \text{PE}_i) $$
$$ W_{\text{total}} = (360 \, \text{J} + 4070.4 \, \text{J}) - (810 \, \text{J} + 0 \, \text{J}) $$
$$ W_{\text{total}} = 4430.4 \, \text{J} - 810 \, \text{J} $$
$$ W_{\text{total}} = 3620.4 \, \text{J} $$
I am told that the answer is wrong from Pearson. I have tried a few other results and got the following: 4610, 4530.96, 3630.96 J.

I belive the answer should be -410 J provided from the equation:
$$ [W=\Delta KE]$$
The total work is the work by all forces.
